# XCTWaiter Expectation not firing

Tags: swift, xcode, automated-tests, xcuitest

I'm using XCTWaiter to wait for certain conditions in a UI automation setup. This is my custom waitFor method:

```
// UITools.swift
public class func waitFor(_ element:Any, timeout:UInt, clause:String) -> Bool
{
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: clause)
    let expectation = testcase.expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element)

    print("Waiting for \(element) to become \"\(clause)\" within \(timeout) seconds ...")

    let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: TimeInterval(timeout))

    switch result
    {
        case .completed:
            return true
        case .invertedFulfillment:
            print("waitFor result is in inverted fulfillment.")
            return true
        case .timedOut:
            print("waitFor result is timed out.")
        case .incorrectOrder:
            print("waitFor result is in incorrect order.")
        case .interrupted:
            print("waitFor result is interrupted.")
    }

    return false
}
```

This method works fine in cases where I wait for XCUIElements but I have a case where I want to wait for a network request to finish so I use a flag that is set to true once the network request is finished. Here's a simplified example:

```
class Hub : NSObject
{
    var isTestRailCasesRetrived = false

    func retrieveTestRailCaseData()
    {
        isTestRailCasesRetrived = false

        testrailClient.getTestCases()
        {
            (response:TestRailModel) in
                // Do processing here ...
                print("Found \(totalCases) TestRail cases for suite with ID \(suite.id).")
                self.isTestRailCasesRetrived = true
        }

        UITools.waitFor(self, timeout: 30, clause: "isTestRailCasesRetrived == true")
    }
}
```

However, the XCTWaiter never reaches a complete and just times out after the timeout. It seems that `isTestRailCasesRetrived` is never evaluated in this situation. Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. This method works successfully in this particular case where above code didn't. It blocks XCUITest code execution until this wait loop is finished ...

```
/// Ass-simple brute force wait method for when nothing else works.
///
public class func waitUntil(timeout:Int = 30, evalblock:@escaping (() -> Bool))
{
    var count = 0
    repeat
    {
        if count >= timeout || evalblock() == true
        {
            break
        }
        else
        {
            Darwin.sleep(1)
        }
        count += 1
    }
    while true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSPredicate works with Objective-C runtime and a properties or functions evaluated by it, must be marked with @objc attribute.

Solution:

```
class Hub : NSObject
{
    @objc var isTestRailCasesRetrived = false

    func retrieveTestRailCaseData()
    {
        isTestRailCasesRetrived = false

        testrailClient.getTestCases()
        {
            (response:TestRailModel) in
                // Do processing here ...
                print("Found \(totalCases) TestRail cases for suite with ID \(suite.id).")
                self.isTestRailCasesRetrived = true
        }

        UITools.waitFor(self, timeout: 30, clause: "isTestRailCasesRetrived == true")
    }
}
```